# Can someone break down the conventions vs. configuration aspects of emberjs?

Tags: ember.js

I get the conceptual aspects of MVC and how they are generally implemented. In emberjs the conventions approach makes sense and is seemingly straightforward. But, how do you decide when to use an objectcontroller vs. an indexedcontroller and such, and how is one to learn or retain the conventions so you can make quick logical programmatic design decisions as to which direction or approach you take?

I mean how do you commit such minute conventions like these into logical thinking?

> If you don't specify a route handler for the post route
>   (App.PostRoute), Ember.js will still render the post template with the
>   app's instance of App.PostController.
>
> If you don't specify the controller (App.PostController), Ember will
>   automatically make one for you based on the return value of the
>   route's model hook. If the model is an Array, you get an
>   ArrayController. Otherwise, you get an ObjectController.
>
> If you don't specify a post template, Ember.js won't render anything!

http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/#toc_route-controller-and-template-defaults

Also, correspondingly are there conventions around views vs. a component vs. a property and how those all funnel out from the conventions around routing, routers, controllers?

thanks -

David

Comment: If you are just getting started, Ember is pretty huge to wrap your head around.  I was there not too long ago.  The core concepts outlined in the beginning of the guides didn't quite click for me until I saw everything in action later on.  Take it with a grain of salt at first and recap when you get further on.

Comment: This is far too vague a request/question for stack overflow. You choose the appropriate controller type for what you are working with. One model would use an `ObjectController`. Multiple models would use an `ArrayController`. `IndexController` would be the name of the controller that manages your index route... It can be either an array or object controller, depending on what the model is.

Answer (score 1):

Controller's are really decorators.  They proxy properties from the controller to the model beneath it.  As such there are three different types of controllers.  `ArrayController`, `ObjectController`, and `Controller`.

`ArrayController` is backed by a collection

`ObjectController` is backed by a single object

`Controller` doesn't have any object backing it

Really the trick is to start small.  Do a single template, single route, single controller.  Don't attempt to add anything else until you run into a problem you don't know how to solve.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sohijunu/1/edit

Once you get the gist of a single route, single controller, single template, you can start experimenting with multiple routes etc.  It's a lot like college, a time of experimentation, but you start small.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/726/edit