# Ember Data, controller properties and caching of data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember and Ember Data to talk to my RESTful API. One of the ways I am fetching data, is through property methods, like this:

```
Em.Controller.extend({  
  categories: function () {
    return this.store.find('category');
  }.property()
});
```

Now when I use `categories` in my template, it correctly fetches the categories and displays these. My question arises when I watch this same query being run for multiple controllers.

Say I have the categories in another controller, I am seeing that the categories are fetched once more for this as if the *store* does not cache the data.

What I expected was that the cache would cache the data, hence eliminating the need to do another API request.

I also experience that individual categories are requested even after all categories are fetched, e.g. in the case where I have a model with a category relation:

```
var entity = DS.Model.extend({
  category: belongsTo('category')
});
```

When this entity is loaded Ember Data makes another request to the API for the particular category which belongs to this *entity* instance.

Am I missing out on something to enable the caching?

Comment: `find` issues an API call. Consider using `all` to get currently cached records.

Comment: @torazaburo How do I do the initial fetching then?

Comment: It really depends on the structure of your app. It may be that you want to refer to one controller which is responsible for reading in and holding the data from the other controllers, doing something like `needs: ['categories'], categoriesBinding: 'controllers.categories.model'` or something similar.

Comment: @torazaburo That's a great idea. That would suit me. However, being fairly new with Ember.js I am not sure how to handle this solution, if the user has not been through the CategoriesController. Then Ember.js complaints that it could not find the controller.

Comment: Or you can just prime your store by calling find in the application route.

Comment: And Ember gets unhappy when you ask it to give you a controller that isn't explicitly defined (it's cool with creating it on it's own when you haven't defined it, but that's when it's asking for it, not when you programmatically ask for it)

Comment: @Kingpin2k I find it dirty to ask for all data on application load. I'm not sure what you mean with "asking for it", do you have something that you can reference me to which explains a solution?

Comment: I figured it out, the *CategoriesController* needs to be explicitly defined. So much for Ember.js magic.

Comment: Like I said 2 comments ago, if you don't have it explicitly defined and it doesn't know what model is going to back it, how would it know what type of controller to create for you?

Comment: And finding it during the application route is a common practice, you're priming the app for your end user in a location that is guaranteed to only hit once.  And if you want it can block the app until it's loaded

Comment: @Kingpin2k Since Ember.js automatically creates the CategoriesController if it's not defined explicitly, I would expect the same to be the case here.

Comment: It only knows how to generate a generic controller based on the fact that you've given it a piece of information (the model).  Without providing it any information it is too specific of a functionality to be able to generate a controller for you without knowing what kind.  I'd suggest reading up on what the controllers are:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023468/can-someone-break-down-the-conventions-vs-configuration-aspects-of-emberjs/25024212#25024212 http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ObjectController.html http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html

Comment: @Kingpin2k Who said I don't provide a model?

Comment: I did.  You might provide a model later, but that's after the controller would have been created, and by that point it would already be one of the 3 types of controllers.  There are two acceptable ways to access a different controller, using `needs` or `controllerFor`, both of which request the controller, without providing any information about a model.